# How to nest repeating groups in QuickFix DataDictionary?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, quickfix, fix-protocol

I am using QuickFix with the Python bindings, and connecting to a counterparty that provides historical data downloads. In order to parse the incoming messages, I need to be able to read **nested** repeating groups.

I found an example of a data dictionary with a nested repeating group here: http://quickfix-j.364392.n2.nabble.com/Nested-repeating-group-error-tag-appears-more-than-once-fwd-td7578213.html

I tried to model my DD on this example but I keep getting the same error: `Conditionally Required Field Missing:3210`. This field 3210 is precisely the new (nested) group definition, called `NoChartData`.

I have pored over the DD and can't find anything wrong with it. Likewise I have triple-checked that every tag is defined and all tags' possible values are also defined.

Any ideas? Is the error my fault? Might it be a QF bug?

**EDIT: I was given a pre-approved data dictionary sample by the counterparty to try, and it did not work (the same error resulted). It seems likely that the DD is not at fault. Is this a bug in the C++ version of QuickFix?**

```
<message name="MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh" msgtype="W" msgcat="app">
      <field name="MDReqID" required="N" />
      <field name="Symbol" required="N" />
      <field name="SecurityType" required="N" />
      <field name="MaturityMonthYear" required="N" />
      <field name="MaturityDay" required="N" />
      <field name="PutOrCall" required="N" />
      <field name="StrikePrice" required="N" />
      <field name="OptAttribute" required="N" />
      <field name="SecurityID" required="N" />
      <field name="SecurityStatus" required="N" />
      <field name="SecurityAltID" required="N" />
      <field name="SecurityExchange" required="N" />
      <field name="SettlType" required="N" />
      <field name="TotalVolumeTraded" required="N" />
      <field name="Currency" required="N" />
      <field name="PriceFeedStatus" required="N" />
      <field name="DeliveryTerm" required="N" />
      <field name="ExecInst" required="N" />
      <field name="ChartType" required="N" /> 
      <field  name="TradeDateStart" required="N" />
      <field  name="TradeDateEnd" required="N" />
      <field  name="SessionStartTime" required="N" />
      <field  name="SessionEndTime" required="N" /> 
      <field  name="DataFormat" required="N" />
      <field name="EncodedTextCRC" required="N"/>
      <field name="EncodedTextLen" required="N" />
      <field name="EncodedText" required="N" />
      <group name="NoMDEntries" required="Y">
          <field name="MDEntryType" required="Y" />
          <field name="TradeDate" required="N" />
          <field name="MDEntryID" required="N" />
          <field name="MDEntryPx" required="N" />                
          <field name="MDEntrySize" required="N" />  
          <field name="MDEntryTime" required="N" />  
          <field name="TickDirection" required="N" /> 
          <field name="TradeCondition" required="N" />    
          <field name="ExecInst" required="N" /> 
          <field name="MDEntryLevel" required="N" />
          <field name="ChartType" required="N" />  
          <field name="MDEntryPositionNo" required="N" />
          <field name="SecondaryOrderID" required="N" />
          <field name="MDEntryState" required="N" />
          <field name="AggressorSide" required="N" />              
          <field name="MDEntrySizeType" required="N" />
          <field name="NumberOfOrders" required="N" />
          <field name="ExactNumOrdersIndicator" required="N" />
          <field name="TrdType" required="N" />
          <field name="TradeVolume" required="N" />
          <group name="NoChartData" required="N" >
              <field  name="Change" required="N" />
              <field  name="Numerator" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="Denominator" required="N" />
              <field  name="PriceCode" required="N" />
              <field  name="TickValue" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="TradeDateCharts" required="N" />  
              <field  name="MarketModeTime" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="MarketMode" required="N" />
              <field  name="SettlementTime" required="N" />  
              <field  name="Settlement" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="HeldSettlementTime" required="N" />  
              <field  name="HeldSettlement" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="OpenInterestTime" required="N" />  
              <field  name="OpenInterest" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="ClearedVolumeTime" required="N" />  
              <field  name="ClearedVolume" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="VWAPTime" required="N" />  
              <field  name="VWAP" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="QuoteTime" required="N" />  
              <field  name="BidTicks" required="N" />
              <field  name="BidRealVolume" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="BidImpliedVolume" required="N" />
              <field  name="OfferTicks" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="OfferRealVolume" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="OfferImpliedVolume" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="TPOStartTime" required="N" />  
              <field  name="TPOTicks" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="TPOVolume" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="TPOVolumeAtBid" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="TPOVolumeAtOffer" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="TPOIsOpening"  required="N" />
              <field  name="TPOIsClosing" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="TradeTime" required="N" />  
              <field  name="TradedVolume" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="TradeTickValue" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="TotalTradedVolume" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="DueToSpread" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="AtBidOrOffer" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="BarStartTime" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="BarCloseTime" required="N" />  
              <field  name="BarOpenTicks" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="BarHighTicks" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="BarLowTicks" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="BarCloseTicks" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="BarVolume" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="BarBidVolume" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="BarOfferVolume" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="BarTradeCount" required="N" />
              <field  name="BarTradesAtBid" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="BarTradesAtOffer" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="TickChangeStartTime" required="N" />   
              <field  name="TickChangeCloseTime" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="TickChangeVolume" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="TickChangeBidVolume" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="TickChangeOfferVolume" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="TickChangeTradeCount" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="TickChangeTradesAtBid" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="TickChangeTradesAtOffer" required="N" />
              <field  name="RFQTime" required="N" />  
              <field  name="BuySell" required="N" /> 
              <field  name="Volume" required="N" />   
          </group>
      </group>                  
  </message>
```

**UPDATE** 
**Here is the beginning of the actual message I am trying to parse:**

(8=FIX.4.2☺9=8233☺35=W☺34=2☺49=CTS☺56=XXXX☺52=20140929-20:11:48.480☺262=k-0
    ☺55=YM☺48=XCME_E YM (Z14)☺207=CME_E☺965=16☺3200=20140903☺3201=20140904☺3202=15:1
    1:48.465☺3203=15:11:48.465☺3204=3☺3205=2☺ **268=2** ☺269=Y☺75=20140904☺ **3210=41** ☺3212=6☺
    3211=20140904☺3212=4☺3216=20140903-21:43:06.701☺3217=16990☺3212=3☺3213=20140903-
    21:45:09.402☺3214=1☺3212=3☺3213=20140903-22:00:00.126☺3214=2☺3212=4☺3216=2014090
    3-23:06:29.533☺3217=16990☺3212=5☺3254=20140903-22:00:00.000☺3255=20140903-22:30:
    34.364☺3256=16990☺3257=16990☺3258=16990☺3259=16990☺3260=2☺3261=0☺3262=2☺3263=2☺3
    264=0☺3265=2☺3212=5☺3254=20140903-23:00:00.000☺3255=20140903-23:17:00.207☺3256=1
    6984☺3257=16984☺3258=16984☺3259=16984☺3260=1☺3261=1☺3262=0☺3263=1☺3264=1☺3265=0☺
    3212=5☺3254=20140904-00:00:00.000☺3255=20140904-00:35:19.271☺3256=16986☺3257=169
    86☺3258=16986☺3259=16986☺3260=1☺3261=0☺3262=1☺3263=1☺3264=0☺3265=1☺3212=11☺3225=
    20140904-06:09:38.473☺3226=1430☺3212=12☺3222=20140904-06:09:38.473☺3223=4957☺321
    2=5☺3254=20140904-01:00:00.000☺3255=20140904-01:04:44.936☺3256=16984☺3257=16984☺
    3258=16984☺3259=16984☺3260=3☺3261=0☺3262=3☺3263=2☺3264=0☺3265=2☺3212=5☺3254=2014
    0904-04:00:00.000☺3255=20140904-04:25:20.988☺3256=16985☺3257=16985☺3258=16985☺32

**And here is the code I am using to parse:**

```
if '3210' in tags: 
    group = fix.Group(3210, 3212) 
    ncd = int(str(message.getField(FIX['3210']))[5:-1])
```

(`FIX` is a dictionary of tag:value pairs.) Then I try to iterate through the `NoChartData` group.

Considering Grant's reply, it would seem I need to change my logic to deal with nested groups.

Comment: Can you post the code that is attempting to read the nested repeating group? Or is QF immediately sending a business reject to the counterparty?

Comment: QF is immediately sending a 35=j (business message reject) message back to counterparty. It's rejected before it gets passed to `fromApp` method. Otherwise my own parsing code would begin. That's why I think it's a QF bug.

Comment: Looking at the `NewOrderList` message definition in the FIX42.xml file that comes with QuickFIX/N, the way it has nested groups is pretty similar to how you are defining the `MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh` message in your DD. It would be clunky to paste in a comment, but you can find it [here on GitHub](https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/blob/7982a22b5657fc746bbfe4536f118bca9f25ce43/spec/fix/FIX42.xml#L1419).

Comment: Next question: does the message you're receiving look to be properly formed? I'm assuming yes, but there's always the chance that there's a mismatch between the DD and the message itself.

Comment: Well, when I request data using the exact same protocol but for 1 day only, everything works. This makes me think their message structure is not the culprit. Having a `NoMDEntries` > 1 is when things crash. This does mean a different message structure. I've done a bit of cursory examination but that is someplace to look if absolutely nothing else works...

Comment: @hunch_hunch, I should have taken your first comment more seriously. I assumed the message wasn't going to `fromApp` but I was wrong about this. Examining the code reading the nesting was the right thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Conditionally Required Field Missing:3210`

That's not a DD error; that's a logic error in your app.

You're trying to extract an optional field that's not present.  You're calling `msg.GetField(3210)` (or whatever), but the message (or group) doesn't contain tag 3210.  QF assumes you know what you're doing and that the field is supposed to be there, so it proceeds like the sender made the mistake.

But QF is being optimistic; *you* probably made the mistake.  (Unless the sender really *was* supposed to include 3210.)

Wrap that `GetField` call call with `if(msg.HasField(3210))` (or whatever the correct function name is).  Don't extract optional fields unless you know they're present or unless you've mandated that the sender should send them.

Comment: I updated the message above to reflect more information. You are wrong that field `3210` isn't there (I work harder than that before turning to SO), but you are more right than wrong -- this is a logic error in my app and you put me on the right track. I should be able to fix this now...

Comment: Were you trying to extract 3210 from the wrong repeating group, or perhaps from the top level instead of a repeating group?  That would account for it.

Comment: That is what I was trying to do, yes. Very wrong. It happened like this: I wrote the code to parse groups over a year ago and had forgotten its niceties. On top of that, the code worked perfectly fine with both `NoChartData` and `NoMDEntries` when the latter was 1, so it never occurred to me that the code was the culprit. The moment I considered the possibility though, it was obvious. Thanks for shaking me out of my nap.